# How do I delete a number of rows in one go in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I run a `selectquery` with a `where` clause to get list of records:

```
Select col1 from mytable  where parkey='A'  limit 1;
Returns 100, 200 , 300, 400
```

I then need to delete all the records returned from select:

```
Delete  from mytable where parkey='A'  and col1 IN (100, 200, 300 , 400)
```

How do I model this requirement?

Would the queries be different for different versions of cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just do a `DELETE FROM mytable WHERE parkey = 'A'`?

Comment: This wasn't clear from your initial question. I would suggest that you properly update the problem description